# Flutter VSCode intellisense not working for single file packages

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

The VSCode Intellisense doesn't provide any suggestions for any single file packages in Flutter.

I've tried this on my own plugin as well as the Webview plugin
https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter

**However**, the Intellisense works if the package is created like this (library keyword is used) -

```dart
library nearby_connections;

export 'src/classes.dart';
export 'src/defs.dart';
export 'src/nearby_connections.dart';
```

Is this some issue via VSCode, can I resolve it somehow by changing some configurations?

Answer (score 0):

Opening a loose file is not currently supported (see https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/issues/602), you need to open a folder. In the latest version of the Dart extension for VS Code, a warning will be shown if you do this explaining how to resolve it.

Comment: But I am opening the complete Flutter Package folder. Its not a single file

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood what you meant by "single file package". When I open the webview_flutter project everything works fine, including completion. If you file a bug at https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code with clear screenshots and details of what you're seeing, I can help debug.